# Nginx service failed to start reason: start-limit-hit'

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, server, systemd

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 with Nginx. (php 7.0 + 7.2)

My nginx service failed, heres the syslog:

```
 Nov 18 06:25:25 FrankFurt2 systemd[1]: Stopping A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Nov 18 06:25:25 FrankFurt2 systemd[1]: Stopped A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Nov 18 06:25:25 FrankFurt2 systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Nov 18 06:25:25 FrankFurt2 nginx[25560]: nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "spabruxelles.be" on 138.68.76.49:80, ignored
Nov 18 06:25:25 FrankFurt2 nginx[25560]: nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.spabruxelles.be" on 138.68.76.49:80, ignored
Nov 18 06:25:25 FrankFurt2 nginx[25566]: nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "spabruxelles.be" on 138.68.76.49:80, ignored
Nov 18 06:25:25 FrankFurt2 nginx[25566]: nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.spabruxelles.be" on 138.68.76.49:80, ignored
Nov 18 06:25:25 FrankFurt2 systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Nov 18 06:25:25 FrankFurt2 systemd[1]: Stopping A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Nov 18 06:25:25 FrankFurt2 systemd[1]: Stopped A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Nov 18 06:25:25 FrankFurt2 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Nov 18 06:25:25 FrankFurt2 systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Nov 18 06:25:25 FrankFurt2 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 18 06:25:25 FrankFurt2 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
```

I'm not sure which and where are the files i should change.
Currently I have 7 domains on that server.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

***start-limit-hit*** is a *systemd* message, it has nothing to do with the actual problem.

---

The relevant log-lines are:

```
conflicting server name "spabruxelles.be" on 138.68.76.49:80, ignored
conflicting server name "www.spabruxelles.be" on 138.68.76.49:80, ignored
conflicting server name "spabruxelles.be" on 138.68.76.49:80, ignored
conflicting server name "www.spabruxelles.be" on 138.68.76.49:80, ignored
```

Most likely those server names are duplicated in your configuration.